# Creating a lookup on a multic-choice column

Tags: lookup-column, choice-field

I have list A with a Status column of Red/Amber/Green and list B which needs to lookup the Status column from column B.

I know you can't do a straight lookup and found this [workaround](https://bramnuyts.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/using-a-lookup-field-on-a-choice-field-) But it doesn't work on multi-choice. It always returns Red. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do straight lookup for multi-choice field type. The recommendation is you create custom form (new form, display form and edit form). In custom forms, you create select HTML element and bind data from Status column. Then once you submit the new form, you create an SharePoint lookup field value and insert into list B.

**References:**

- SharePoint 2013: Building Custom Forms: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx

Comment: Thanks @DuyVo, am I missing something? I wasn't talking about creating a form?

Comment: @Dazza: There is another approach if you don't want to create custom forms. You can use JS Link to do the same way like I mention above.
Reference: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a